# passing different arrays parameters in pact

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, pact

I have two api calls , with the only difference being in the array parameters :

```
// it is used for displaying whole list  
Query 1 : limit=25&var1=[deleted=false] 

//it is used for displaying on basis of id
Query 2 : limit=25&var1=[deleted=false,id=10005]
```

I tried using  term , also something like but it takes both the query as one

```
var1: term({
generate: '[deleted=false]',
matcher: '[deleted=false]'}),

var1: term({
generate:'[deleted=false,id=10005]',
matcher:'[deleted=false,id=10005]'}),
```

Also , i passed the exact query but it doesn't  work

Any suggestions on how to do it ?

Comment: Can you please provide a github repo we can use to reproduce the issue? As a guess, it might be that your matcher is not using a valid regular expression `[` and `]` are special characters in regex.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to using dynamic legnth array type by parameter in javascript, Use this.

```
var [deleted, id, ...any] = parameter;
console.log(deleted, id);
```

In case, if you throw parameter([deleted]), log be printed by "`deleted, id is undefined`".

Comment: The question is related to use of the pact framework, not standard js array items